# Spring Redis cache expiration in memory

Tags: spring-data-redis, spring-cache, redisson

Using Spring Redis cache and wonder if is possible to set some data cache duration in memory. Cache of cache. If i know that data in Redis will not change for 5 minutes i dont need that Spring Redis cache touch the Redis everytime when some @Cacheable method is called.
Is Redisson the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, [Redisson](https://redisson.org/) is simply a client-side facade or enhanced Redis (Java) client used to interface with a Redis node (or cluster) in a more powerful and convenient way, not unlike [Spring Data Redis](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-redis/). For example, and as you already know, [using Redis as a *caching provider*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:support:cache-abstraction) in *Spring's Cache Abstraction*.

Redis does seem to support [client-side caching](https://redis.io/docs/manual/client-side-caching/) (a local cache in addiion to the remote (server) cache?), when using a Redis client/server topology. This would be transparent to you application (e.g. `@Cacheable`) and configured in the Redis client driver, AFAIK.

However, given my lack of experience with Redis, or even Redisson for matter, I cannot speak to this feature in detail. Redis client-side caching may need to be supported by the Redis client drivers (e.g. [Jedis](https://github.com/redis/jedis), [Lettuce](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core), even Redisson, etc).

NOW THE LONG-WINDED ANSWER FOR THE INTERESTED READER:

What you are describing when you state a "cache of cache" hearsay, is really having a "locally available cache" in addition to the "remote, or server-side cache". This assumes, of course, you are running Redis in a client/server (not embedded), and possibly distributed/clustered (maybe HA), capacity in the first place.

Ideally, you would choose a *caching provider* that supported this sort of arrangement out-of-the-box, natively. And, despite popular belief (for [example](https://www.credera.com/insights/an-introduction-to-redis-cluster)), much of what Redis "reinvented" (horizontal scale-out or cluster, HA, even persistence) already existed in other, more mature solutions, built from the ground up with these concerns in mind.

> SIDENOTE: Granted, the referenced article above is dated, but also a bit naive.

A "cache of (a) cache" is technically referred to as the ***Near Caching* pattern**.

It is where the "local" (application/client-side) cache mirrors the "remote" (server-side and primary) cache to avoid [a] network hop(s), i.e. latency, by only accessing the remote cache when necessary (e.g. cache miss), preferably in a "single-hop", "fault-tolerant" fashion, when the server-side is distributed and clustered.

However, a fundamental difference between the local cache and server-side, remote cache is that the local cache only stores a subset of the data from the remote cache based on "interests".

> NOTE: In Redis's documentation, they referred to this as "tracking". There are different ways, across different providers, to express "interests" or track what the client has accessed. Be mindful of the different approaches here since they consume different system resources.

You might have a distributed (Web / Microservice) application architecture where several client application instances serve different demographics or populations of end-users. Clearly, those client application instances might use shared, but different subsets of the primary dataset stored in the servers. This is where the local cache and "registering interest" only in the data that matters to, or is used by, the client application comes into play.

"Registering interest" is important since the server-side, remote cache can notify clients ("push", rather than a client "pulling") hosting a local cache when data on the server changes that a client is interested in since more than 1 client might have interest in and use the same data (e.g. "record", and the intersection of data).

So, how do we properly address this concern without unnecessarily introducing extra (layers of) complexity into our system/application architecture?

Well, for one, it starts by choosing the right *caching provider* for the problem at hand.

> DISCLAIMER: my experience stems from [Apache Geode](https://geode.apache.org/), which is the OSS variate of [VMware Tanzu GemFire](https://tanzu.vmware.com/gemfire) and a I am responsible for all things ***Spring for Apache Geode*** at VMware.

While I am a bit biased here it is not uncommon for other *caching providers* (and complete IMDG solutions) to support the same arrangement. For example, 1 of my personal favorites is **Hazelcast**.

Hazelcast calls this particular caching arrangement, or topology, an "embedded" cache and even refers to this as "near cache" in the [documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/cache/overview).

The nice thing about a local, embedded "Near Cache" is that it avoids latency through unnecessary networks hops, however, interest registration is key to keep data consistent, as far as possible.

I have documented, talked about and even demonstrated different *caching patterns* when using *Spring for Apache Geode* in the *Spring Boot for Apache Geode* documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-caching-provider-look-aside-near-inline-multi-site) and [Near Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-caching-provider-near-caching) in particular, along with the [Near Caching Sample](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/guides/caching-near.html) in the [Samples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/index.html#geode-samples) with the other *caching patterns*).

I am sure you can find similar resources with other *caching providers*, even Redis.

At any rate, this documentation should help you understand different concerns to be aware of (e.g. memory consumption) when choosing any topology and configuration.

Good luck!

Comment: Wow. Great answer :) tHx. This is exactly me case. We area calling HA Redis cluster and i want to reduce network trafic. Also looking for Near Caching pattern.

Comment: Nice! Glad this was able to help. If you have other questions, feel free to post back here in the comments or open a new `#spring-cache` question. I monitor it quite regularly.  Cheers!